# Is Transit Visa needed for Tokyo

Tags: visas, transit, transit-visas

I have upcoming business flight between Houston and Bali, Singapore, This flight has a 2-hour layover in Tokyo, and and a plane change Do I need transit visas beyond a business VISA for Singapore?

Comment: In short, no, anybody can do an international-international transit at Tokyo (Narita).

Comment: However, Bali is in Indonesia, while Singapore is its own country.  I hope you've got the visa for the right place?